# Angular fire - $add function is not found

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app using `angularFire`. When I am trying to add a element to firebase array I am getting error

**chatRoomMessageArray.$add is not a function**.

Here is the code:

```
this.sendMessage = function(chatRoomId, messagetext){

       var chatRoomFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/messages');

        // Get firebaseArray sync object from this chatRoom
        var chatRoomMessageArray = $firebaseArray(chatRoomFirebaseRef);

        var current_timestamp = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

        // Create a message object
        var msgObject = {
                            'message':messagetext,
                            'senderId':this.userId,
                            'created_on':current_timestamp,
                            'updated_on':current_timestamp
                        };


        var promiseOfNewObjRef = chatRoomMessageArray.$add(msgObject);  --> $add throws an error

        return promiseOfNewObjRef;

    },
```

Can any one help me out what is the issue ?

I have tried solutions like using `$asArray` and other but nothing is working out.

Currently I am using `2.2.4-firebase.js` and `1.2.0-angularfire.min.js` .

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try `console.log(chatRoomMessageArray.$add());` ?  It should log something like this `i {$$state: Object}`

Answer (score 0):

I was a mistake from my side.

When I was injecting `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject` in controller their sequence was not correct in function arguments ..

```
module.controller('$firebaseArray' , '$firebaseObject' , function($firebaseObject , $firebaseArray))
```

It should be

```
module.controller('$firebaseArray' , '$firebaseObject' , function( $firebaseArray,$firebaseObject)
```

My bad :) ..

Anyway thanks all